# Обучение CNN после нескольких эпох обучение останавливается на примерно одном уровне точности

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, python-3.6, keras

Стоит задача распознать такую капчу:

[image: Пример капчи]

После разбиения картинки получаем следующее:

[image: Отдельные символы капчи]

Всего на выходе получается 1320 картинок.
Вот этот код пытается обучиться распознавать такую капчу:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, Activation
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
import glob
import cv2

samples = []
samples_ans = []

for filename in glob.glob('v1/v1*'):
    answer = filename.split('\\')[1].replace('.jfif', '').replace('v1_', '').split('_')[0]

    samples.append(cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
    samples_ans.append([int(answer)])

x_train, y_train = np.array(samples), np.array(samples_ans)



y_train = to_categorical(y_train)


x_train = x_train.reshape(1320, 70, 35, 1)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(70, 35, 1)))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))


model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=16)

model.save_weights('./test.csv')

print(model.predict(x_train[:3]))
```

Но после нескольких эпох обучение просто останавливается на уровне 11-13% точности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого момента параметр `loss` не меняется в течении >50 эпох, а точность скачет на 1-2%.

Answer (score 1):

У вас несколько логических ошибок:

- функция активации `sigmoid` используется только в задачах бинарной классификации (т.е. если в предсказываемом столбце всего два значения: да/нет, 0/1, и т.д.) и обычно *только* на выходном слое нейронной сети, во всех внутренних / скрытых слоях используют нелинейные функции активации типа `relu`
- в задачах мультиклассовой классификации на выходном слое используют функцию активации `softmax`
- скорее всего если правильно подобрать архитектуру НС, то ваша модель начнет переобучаться, чтобы компенсировать это обычно добавляют `Dropout()` слой(и) для регуляризации, который разрушает определенный процент нейронных связей, что способствует более грубой (общей) модели и уменьшает эффект переобучения

Comment: С моей реализаций точность сети достигает ~99.3%, попробовал поставить в скрытых слоях функцию активации 'relu' и 'softmax' на выходе, теперь сеть вообще не обучается. Если поменять кол-во нейронов на 128, 64, 64 в 1,2,3-тем слое соответственно, ситуация не меняется.

Возможно и принято и правильно ставить 'relu', 'softmax', но тем не менее моя реализация работает.

Comment: @Bleno, вы проверяли вашу модель на тестовой выборке? какая точность на тестовых (те которые модель не видела во время обучения) изображениях? И еще вы уверены что у вас есть картинки с цифрами отличными от `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Для решения этой задачи надо просто поставить меньшее кол-ко нейронов, в итоге всё выглядит вот так:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(70, 35, 1)))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```